# How to read XAML(WPF) using Java?

Tags: java, wpf, xaml

A display converter has been implemented, converting xaml displays into a native xml format for a Java application.
It was written in .NET, but the code is transferred.
For maintainability purposes, rewriting in Java is considered.

My Question: What are the options to read/parse XAML files using Java?

Comment: Although this question has already been answered, the [eclipse plugin eFace](http://www.soyatec.com/eface/) could be an alternative way, it allows editing and using XAML in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that XAML is en enhancement of XML you could go with XML parsers like [explained here](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2013/05/23/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java/) and see if these libraries can get all out of your XAML that you search for.

Comment: hmm..  looks like there's no framework for reading XAML data other than just parsing XML it ourself.